# Let $f(x)=x^2-2$ with $x\in [-2,2]$. Show that the equation $f^{n}(x)=x$ has $2^{n}$ real roots. [Where $f^{n}(x)=f(f^{n-1}(x))$]

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification

Let $f(x)=x^2-2$ with $x\in [-2,2]$. Show that the equation $f^{n}(x)=x$ has $2^{n}$ real roots. [Where $f^{n}(x)=f(f^{n-1}(x))$]

**My solution:**

Let $x=2\cos(\theta)$ for $\theta\in [0,\pi]$

$\implies$
$f(x)=4\cos^2 (\theta)-2=2\cos(2\theta)$

$f(f(x))=(f(x))^2-2=(2\cos^22\theta)^2-2=2(2\cos^{2}2\theta-1)=2\cos(2^2 \theta)$

$\implies$$f(f(x))=2\cos(4\theta)$

Similarly $f(f(f(x)))=2\cos(2^3\theta)$

$\vdots$

$\underbrace {f\circ f\circ\cdots \circ f}_\text{n times}(x)=2\cos(2^n \theta)$

$\implies$

From Question i.e, $f^{n}(x)=x$

$\implies$

$2\cos(2^n\theta)=2\cos\theta$

$\implies$

$2^n\theta=2m\pi \pm \theta$

$\implies$

$\theta=\dfrac{2m\pi}{2^{n}-1}$ $\quad$ or $\quad$ $\theta=\dfrac{2m\pi}{2^{n}+1}$ $\forall \; \theta \in [0,\pi]$

Checking Result for $n=1$

$\theta=\dfrac{2m\pi}{1}\;$ or $\; \theta=\dfrac{2m\pi}{3}$

$\implies$ $\theta = \dfrac{2\pi}{3}, 0$ i.e., $2$ solution.

Checking Result for $n=2$

$\theta=\dfrac{2m\pi}{3}\;$ or $\; \theta=\dfrac{2m\pi}{5}$

$\implies$ $0, \dfrac{2\pi}{3},\dfrac{2\pi}{5},\dfrac{4\pi}{5}$ i.e. $4$ solution.

$\implies$ There are $2^{n}$ distinct root of $f^{n}(x)=x\;$ equation.

**Is my Solution Correct?**

Comment: Have you done the proof that $f^n(x) = 2 \cos 2^n \theta$? You did the case when $n=1$ explicitly, but you didn't write the induction step from $n-1$ to $n$. It is similar to how you did the base case but with $\theta \to 2^{n-1} \theta$.

Comment: @AHusain Yes, I've done the proof that $f^{n}(x)=2\cos(2^{n}\theta)$. I did not write the induction steps.

Comment: Have an idea for a sketch. Prove that there are two fixed points without iteration. That's just solving a quadratic equation. Then prove that each time you iterate the function, you duplicate it the interval, with each distorted duplicate preserving the number of fixed points. From there it follows that the number of fixed points double at each iteration.

Comment: @AHusain I've done some correction in my solution. Is it now correct?

Comment: @TurlocTheRed I've done some correction in my solution. Is it now correct?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials), given what you've already figured out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your idea is very nice.

I would add proofs for the following claims :

**Claim 1** : $f^{n}(2\cos\theta)=2\cos(2^n\theta)$ (your idea is very nice, but I would prove this claim by induction rigorously)

**Claim 2** : The number of integers $m$ such that $0\leqslant\dfrac{2m\pi}{2^{n}-1}\leqslant\pi$ is $2^{n-1}$, and the number of integers $M$ such that $0\leqslant\dfrac{2M\pi}{2^{n}+1}\leqslant\pi$ is $2^{n-1}+1$.

**Claim 3** : $\dfrac{2m\pi}{2^{n}-1}=\dfrac{2M\pi}{2^{n}+1}$ holds if and only if $m=M=0$.

(It follows from Claim 2 and 3 that $f^n(x)=x$ has $2^{n-1}+(2^{n-1}+1)-1=2^n$ real roots.)

---

**Claim 1** : $f^{n}(2\cos\theta)=2\cos(2^n\theta)$.

*Proof* : If $n=1$, $f(2\cos\theta)=(2\cos\theta)^2-2=2(2\cos^2\theta-1)=2\cos(2\theta)$. Suppose that $f^{n}(2\cos\theta)=2\cos(2^n\theta)$. Then, $f^{n+1}(2\cos\theta)=(f^n(2\cos\theta))^2-2=2(2\cos^2(2^n\theta)-1)=2\cos(2^{n+1}\theta)$.$\ \square$

---

**Claim 2** : The number of integers $m$ such that $0\leqslant\dfrac{2m\pi}{2^{n}-1}\leqslant\pi$ is $2^{n-1}$, and the number of integers $M$ such that $0\leqslant\dfrac{2M\pi}{2^{n}+1}\leqslant\pi$ is $2^{n-1}+1$.

*Proof* : Since $0\leqslant\dfrac{2m\pi}{2^{n}-1}\leqslant\pi\iff 0\leqslant m\leqslant 2^{n-1}-1$, the number of such integers $m$ is $2^{n-1}$. Since $0\leqslant\dfrac{2M\pi}{2^{n}+1}\leqslant\pi\iff 0\leqslant M\leqslant 2^{n-1}$, the number of such integers $M$ is $2^{n-1}+1$.$\ \square$

---

**Claim 3** : $\dfrac{2m\pi}{2^{n}-1}=\dfrac{2M\pi}{2^{n}+1}$ holds if and only if $m=M=0$.

*Proof* : Since $m=\dfrac{(2^n-1)M}{2^n+1}$ with $\gcd(2^n-1,2^n+1)=\gcd(2^n-1,2)=1$, $M$ has to be a multiple of $2^n+1$. It follows from $0\leqslant M\leqslant 2^{n-1}$ that $M=m=0$.$\ \square$